# How to prevent console errors showing in UI?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

How to prevent showing logs of console messages in UI view ? I hate this. I think that shouldn't be.
[image]

All errors should be still in console of IDE . Am I right ?

Comment: I used Vaadin version 7.3 with valo Theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a section dedicated to this in the book of vaadin

https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/application.errors.html#application.errors.unchecked-exceptions

> You can customize the default error handling by implementing a custom ErrorHandler and enabling it with setErrorHandler() in any of the components in the component hierarchy, including the UI, or in the VaadinSession object. You can either implement the ErrorHandler or extend the DefaultErrorHandler. In the following example, we modify the behavior of the default handler.

Comment: Thanks for exact solution link.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that... Nice way of adding a generic message handler. I currently have my code wrapped to popup a failure window that sends me an email for unexpected errors. This would remove need of that!!! +1

Answer (score 2):

I've been using vaadin for 3+ years, and there is no easy way to stop this. The only way to effectively stop this, is to make sure that all your components are wrapped effectively in try/catch blocks, and that you handle any expected/unexpected errors yourself.

Be aware that you can put messages onto components yourself using:

```
somecomponent.setComponentError(new UserError("some error message"));
```